# How to get Publication modification history?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager

Is there any way to track the users who have modified a specific Publication (metadata or properties). Because Tridion does not keep the versioning history for a publication.

My Investigation:

- When I checked the **Tridion_cm** database (dbo.PUBLICATIONS table), found the last modification date but I haven't found who has modified
- I have checked couples of other tables also but haven't found sufficient info

My Code -

```
[TcmExtension("TridionEventSystem")]
    public class PublicationSaveEvent: TcmExtension
    {
        public PublicationSaveEvent()
        {
            Subscribe();
        }
        public void Subscribe()
        {
            // Subscribe Your Event
            EventSystem.Subscribe<Publication, SaveEventArgs>(OnPublicationSavePre, EventPhases.Initiated);
        }
        private static void OnPublicationSavePre(Publication pub, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            pub.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already pointed out, Tridion's versioning does not apply to Publications. However, you could make use of the Event System and write a simple piece of code which captures and persists the relevant information. Use a combination of `Publication` (or `Repository`) and `SaveEventArgs`. Also, don't forget to deploy your ES code to all your CMs (in a scaled out setup).

**UPDATE**

Try the following snippet for getting the user who initiated the `Save` action.

`pub.Session.User`

Do note that `Session.User` property is Deprecated starting Web 8.5

Comment: Hi @atila, I have implement the Event System code to get the publication modification versioning but did not get any information when i use 'Publication' and 'SaveEventArgs'. Please refer the below code and suggest me how I can proceed futher.

Comment: [TcmExtension("TridionEventSystem")]
    public class PublicationSaveEvent: TcmExtension
    {
        public PublicationSaveEvent()
        {
            Subscribe();
        }
        public void Subscribe()
        {
            // Subscribe Your Event
            EventSystem.Subscribe<Publication, SaveEventArgs>(OnPublicationSavePre, EventPhases.Initiated);
        }
        private static void OnPublicationSavePre(Publication pub, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            pub.
        }
    }

Comment: Can you please update your answer with this snippet, it's hard to read from the comment. Just use the 'edit' function.

Comment: Hi Atila, I have provided the code snippet on above. Please refer and provide your comments

Comment: Hi @Atila, I have given my code on above section. Could you please provide any comments?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Hi Atila, Thank you very much for this information and support.